# Callback for when obj changes position?

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript, 3ds

In MaxScript, how would I detect if an object has been moved with an event? I have tried detecting transform but this doesn't work:

```
when transform $Body do (
  print"moved"
)
```

It also cannot freeze the ui or the program, since it has to detect when an object is actively moving.

Comment: Don't hardcode the path to the scene object using $Body.

Comment: I hard coded it because the object will always be named $Body

Answer (score 1):

Your forgot the `changes` keyword. The correct syntax is

```
when transform $Body changes do (
    print "moved"
)
```

Comment: I see, the transform is for when the object is resized, not for when position changes. I need to detect when position changes.

Comment: It's for any changes in object's transform - as the reference says, _Signaled when the transform of an object is changed such as, by a move, rotate, or scale._ In what way are you changing the position?

Comment: I am changing the position using keys in my frames.

Answer (score 1):

An already key-framed node will not trigger this handler it is not being driven by the user, but by the system.

This will not trigger when you press play in the trackbar.

Without knowing exactly what you intend to do it's difficult to recommend an alternative.

If you wish to report the position or transform information of a specific node when the trackbar/currentTime changes, you could use registerTimeCallback  and unRegisterTimeCallback .

```
fn reportObject =
(
    print $Box001.pos
)
registerTimeCallback reportObject
```

This will trigger when the play button is used, or when you scrub the time bar. Read the documentation regarding timecallbacks as they have specific rules.

Hopefully this helps.